# What is the design consideration of setting default worker thread count as (availableProcessors * 2) in Netty?

Tags: performance, asynchronous, concurrency, netty, nio

availableProcessors * 2

Why is it and does it has some special design consideration here?

Is it a value somehow got from performance turning experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is from experience and often a good starting point. How many you really need depends a bit on how many concurrent connections you have and what are the processing times within your ChannelHandlers.

The best way to find out is to attach a profiler and check how busy the Threads are etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Then I wonder why the default setting **maxThreads** for Tomcat 7 is: _The maximum number of request processing threads to be created by this Connector, which therefore determines the maximum number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. If not specified, this attribute is set to **200**._   **Why such a big difference for same (similar) thing (worker threads count) ?**

Comment: Tomcat is not asynchronous and non-blocking i guess. In Tomcat you need as many threads as many simultaneous connections you would like to process. Netty can handle thousands of connections with only a few threads.